# Composite Primary Key on partitioned tables, and Foreign Keys

Tags: sql-server, database-design, partitioning, foreign-key, primary-key

We have a database where several tables are partitioned. The primary key (PK for brevity) for these tables is of the form

- *transaction_date, id*

Where *transaction_date* is the partitioning key, and *id* is a unique integer column. If we were not partitioning the table, then we would only use *id* as the PK.

We have several other tables which need foreign keys (FKs) to reference these partitioned tables. I cannot decide whether to use composite FKs, referencing both columns of the PK, or single column FKs, referencing the *id* column supported by a unique index.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages of either approach? So far the only factors I can think of (and I may even be wrong on these) are:

- Single column FK: Reduces app development complexity.
- Composite FK: Allows partition elimination when joining on FK columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ALL** unique constraints involved in a partitioning scenario **MUST** have the partition column defined as part of the base index definition (subset of the index key) - (not merely an included column). In other words, you will not be able to create a unique constraint on ***just*** the `ID` column in this scenario.

Set up a partition function and scheme.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_dbo_Test] (DATE) AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR VALUES ('2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2081-03-01')
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS_dbo_Test] AS PARTITION [PF_dbo_test] 
TO ([PRIMARY],[PRIMARY],[PRIMARY],[PRIMARY])
```

---

Create a table with a `PRIMARY KEY` that references the partition scheme.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Test]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TransactionDate] DATE
    ,[ID] INT CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransactionDate] ASC) 
    ) ON PS_dbo_Test (TransactionDate)
```

---

Now, try to create a unique constraint on the partitioned table without specifying the partition column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_Test] ON [dbo].[Test] ([ID] ASC)
    WITH (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF
            ,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
            ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
            ,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
            ,DROP_EXISTING = OFF
            ,ONLINE = OFF
            ,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
            ,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
            )
```

---

> Msg 1908, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Column 'TransactionDate' is
>   partitioning column of the index 'UX_Test'. Partition columns for a
>   unique index must be a subset of the index key.

---

So, when you ask the question:

> I cannot decide whether to use composite FKs, referencing both columns
>   of the PK, or single column FKs, referencing the id column supported
>   by a unique index.

I'm afraid SQL Server has decided for you. You will have to define your FK's with both `TransactionDate` AND `ID`.